# jquery wont add class to html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to toggle a class to html tag when someone click on button. 
My button has a ID vertical-grid (#vertical-grid) and when i click on button nothing happens?

```
<script>
$("#vertical-grid").click(function(e){
    $("html").toggleClass("vertical-rhythm-grid");
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

This is html of a button

```
<a id="vertical-grid" class="btn bggreen" href="#" role="button">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

I don't know if it matters but my HTML tag already has a no-js class

```
<html class="no-js" lang="">
```

Comment: maybe you have error in console

Comment: no, i added it to the bottom of body, is that ok or thats where the mistake is?

Comment: @riogrande: how are you adding the button??

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, just made this: https://jsfiddle.net/h17a471q/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar html? i copied button on my question?

Comment: is maybe modernizer causing the problem? @LongNguyen

Comment: @riogrande: *"no, i added it to the bottom of body, is that ok or thats where the mistake is?"* If you mean you added that `script` tag to the end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag, then that's definitely okay, yes. Any elements defined by the HTML above it will be available to script code.

Comment: @riogrande: See guardio's comment above, my guess is that you have an error you're not seeing. It'll be in the web console.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and also i put it below the jquery so if i put it in the head it would not work because of that

Comment: @riogrande: Best place for scripts is right at the end, sounds like you're doing the right thing.

Comment: We are assuming you know how to check for errors in the console...

Comment: chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
base.js:4381 SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.
chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: @Vi100 please check my previous comment, im getting 3 from the console

Comment: The code in the question definitely works, even with modernizr: http://jsbin.com/kosepujoga/edit

Comment: You've something that's preventing your code from executing. The code is ok. From your comments it could be some extension that you've installed on chrome. Check your code in another browser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, the modernizer is not causing the problem, neither is ionicons or google fonts... below i only have jquery and im sure he is not blocking my script

Comment: JQuery must be declared before your script, not below, as you're using it in your code...

Comment: @Vi100 yes it is i already discussed that, everything is ok in syntax, but yes you were right, it was one of chromes extension, its working in firefox

Comment: Solved then. Pleased to help!

Answer (score 1):

There might be many reasons for it why it is not working.

Like:

> 1. You may have used same id twice or more in that page.
> 2. Jquery Conflict.
> 3. Jquery Library not loaded properly.

To solve these types of problem always try to look once in firebug console. It helps to solve problem very easily.

If you can see your error in your console just comment it here I will try to help you.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the bug was in one of chromes extensions as the code works in other browsers!

Comment: Try to check your code on chrome by enabling private mode or disable your extensions, if it works then try to use jQuery.noConflict(). it might help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#vertical-grid', function(e){
    $("html").toggleClass("vertical-rhythm-grid");
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `addClass`function:

```
<script>
$("#vertical-grid").click(function(e){
    $("html").addClass("vertical-rhythm-grid");
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer but my code is working, chrome extensions are causing the problem!